# primeng p-fullcalendar prev next click capture

Tags: fullcalendar, primeng

I am trying to capture the month and year when the "prev" or "next" buttons are clicked on the primeng p-fullcalendar. I tried (viewRender)="fetchEvents($event)", but its not firing the fetchEvents function. Anybody has any ideas? Thanks.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="col-8">
     <p-fullCalendar #fc [events]="meetingList" [options]="options" (viewRender)="fetchEvents($event)"></p-fullCalendar>
</div>
```

Here is the ts code:

```
meetinglist: any;

    ngOnInit() {


     this.meetingList = [
                {
                    "title": "Meeting-1",
                    "start": "2019-02-12"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Meeting-2",
                    "start": "2019-02-14"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Appointment-1",
                    "start": "2019-02-16"
                },

            ];

      this.options = {
          defaultDate: '2019-02-10'
          ,height: 'parent'
      }

    }

    public fetchEvents(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

How do I get the month and year when the prev or next button is clicked on the p-calendar?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we have some chance of being able to reproduce your issue. From your tiny snippet of code it's really not easy to be sure what is going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Added code.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I see you are trying to fetch events every time the view is rendered. That's not how fullCalendar is designed to work. In fact if it succeeded you'd cause an infinite loop because the act of rendering events itself causes the view to be re-rendered.

Comment: If you want to go back to the server for new events whenever the calendar is displaying a different view, or a different time period, fullCalendar will handle this for you automatically, if you specify your event feed as a dynamic one - you can use one of these two patterns: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed (directly specifying a URL to download events from) or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function (specifying a function to run which will be called by fullCalendar every time the view/date changes, and which it expects to return a new set of events fetched from some source).

Comment: Actually, I am trying to find out the year and month so that I can use those information to fetch another set of data (unrelated to the p-calendar data) to display on another part of the page.  So, in order to do that I need to know when the prev, next buttons were clicked and what the month year values are.

Comment: And btw, I am using p-fullcalendar component from primeng.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this;
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qqwdyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

to get the Month and Year on prev and next clicks:
console.log(this.fullCalendar.calendar.view.title);

Comment: Answers should be self contained. Do not rely on external sources.